# passing data to javascript on page load

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, javascript, parameters

I want to pass data to id

```
<script language="javascript" src="/foo.aspx?id=1"></script>
```

I have this code in a aspx page.

The data should be passed on load, before this code is being executed.

how can i do that?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do by making the src attribute dynamic?

Comment: I assume there's a server that's emitting different javascript depending on the URL parameters, and he doesn't know what they should be until runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've gotten more and more averse to putting <% %> in the .aspx file, mostly because you can get into terrible knots trying to escape various kinds of quotes.

Here's another way of doing it:

```
<asp:Literal id="myscript" runat="server"/>
```

Then on the server side, when you're handling `Page_Load()`:

```
int theID = 42;
myscript.Text = string.Format("<script type=\"text/javascript\" " +
           " src=\"/foo.aspx?id={0})\"></script>", theID);
```

**Edit**: rewritten in C# :)

Comment: This is a good workaround, and I've used it for databound controls where a link's click function is dependent on its id.  The better way to handle injecting the whole javascript is done with `Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerclientscriptblock.aspx  However, if you need to make code changes in the future to your javascript, you have to recompile your whole codebase, as opposed to making changes in the web form and moving around the `<%= %>` tag.

Comment: @Jim Schubert: I agree, of course, though I think you meant http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9.aspx . On the other hand, sometimes you need to control where exactly on the page the script is placed.

Comment: yes your link points to the ClientScript.* version.  I actually prefer this version because there is an overload for automatically including script tags, so you only supply the javascript.  Adding the script tags is usually what gets me with the mismatched quotes.

Answer (score 3):

Just have a property in your code-behind file, like

```
protected string FooId
{
    get { return ... }
}
```

Then in the ASPX file, reference it like this:

```
<script language="javascript" src="/foo.aspx?id=<%= FooId %>"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET has a syntax `<%= %>` which is equivalent to Response.Write.

You can then store your id in a property, e.g.:
`protected int Id {get;set;}` and set it in Page_Load

then, you'll do this:

`<script language="javascript" src="/foo.aspx?id=<%= Id %>"></script>`